# How to print exceptions from Cucumber runs including runtime exceptions

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I would like to collect the exception message(eg: Assertion Error) during cucumber runs to a logfile/textfile. I understand that we can use custom formatters or 'Result' class from Cucumber, but I have no idea how to use it. Tried going through cucumber docs but couldn't find anything significant other than that for in Ruby Language.

From another question in stackoverflow, I have understood that we can use the Result class as follows:

```
public String getResult(Result result) {
String error = result.getError();
return error;
}
```

If some could elaborate me in which context, shall I use "result", it would be really helpful. I use Cucumber with Java, and Junit Runner.

Comment: What is the cucumber version?

Comment: I am using cucumber version: '1.2.5'. Thanks

Comment: when a step fails cucumber automatically prints out the exception details in the report. Do you want an additional report just mentioning exception stacktrace?

Comment: have a look at this. https://automationrhapsody.com/create-cucumber-jvm-custom-formatter/

Comment: @Grasshopper - Thanks.   I will go through this.